# zend mysql caching in php for increasing the performance of webpages

Tags: zend-framework

we are hosting a site in shared domain where we dont have memcache and APC services installed.On the other hand in one of our tables,in that table data is around 11,00,000 rows.We want to implement zend mysql caching in our system for caching of mysql query results caching.Please guide me on how to implement zend caching for our case??

Answer (score 0):

If you are using zend framework then it's different case this example is for using zend framework(version 1.*) library. You can download library from [Zend Framework](http://framework.zend.com/downloads/latest)

```
include 'library/Zend/Cache.php';//include zend cache library

// set cache options
$frontendOptions = array(
   'lifetime' => null, // cache lifetime of 2 hours
   'automatic_serialization' => true
);

$backendOptions = array(
    'cache_dir' => './tmp/' // Directory where to put the cache files
);

// getting a Zend_Cache_Core object
$cache = Zend_Cache::factory('Core',
                             'File',
                             $frontendOptions,
                             $backendOptions);


// see if a cache already exists:
if( ($result = $cache->load('myresult')) === false ) {

    // cache miss; connect to the database

    mysql_connect('localhost', 'user', 'password');
    mysql_select_db('test');
    $query = 'select * from users';
    $rs = mysql_query($query);
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($rs))
    {
        $result[] = $row;
    }


    $cache->save($result, 'myresult');

} else {

    // cache hit! shout so that we know
    echo "This one is from cache!\n\n";

}

print_r($result);
```

You can find more details here http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.cache.introduction.html